# How do you define an HTTP object?

Tags: http, networking, web, network-programming

My books and lecturers say that non-persistent HTTP connections open up seperate TCP connections for every HTTP object (wikipedia says "for every HTTP request/response pair").

But how do you define what an HTTP object is? A website with 10 images, 3 videos and 10 different HTML paragraphs of text. How many objects is this?
Is the website just one object and so we need only one HTTP request and one TCP connection? Or is this 23 different HTTP objects?

Is it correct if I say that you need one HTTP request for the website, then 10 new for the images, 3 new for the vidoes? But what about the text?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need a connection for each of those... except the text, text is part of the html so its downloaded within the same file.

Usual process:

- Open connection download webpage (html file text is included unless
  each is injected into the page ie ajax request etc then its a http connection for each of those)
- parse images etc urls
- open connection for each image, video, swf, javascript, css etc file

Comment: Thanks! :) So we define an HTTP object pretty much as something the HTML document is referencing to? (thanks for adding the examples at the end, by the way)

Answer (score 0):

You would have one connection for the html on the website, including the text if it's directly in the html (if each paragraph is in it's own iframe, then it'd be a connection a piece),  plus you'd have one for each image and one for each video.

Answer (score 0):

A single HTTP request is done for each file: one for the HTML file that contains the page's text and markup, one each for the image files, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an 'HTTP object', so your question doesn't really make sense.

There are *resources* which are fetched via HTTP URLs.

Basically every src= attribute in an HTML page names another resource, and the page itself is a resource of course.

Comment: Yes, resources are required HTTP objects :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP object** is just the most general term meaning "something identified by URL" :) It's being used in HTTP specifications (Completely unrelated to Object Oriented Programming):

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Request.html

Regarding the **TCP/IP** question:

A browser can pool connections, which means it can reuse established TCP (and TLS) for more subsequent requests saving some overhead. This is controlled by the `Connection: keep-alive` HTTP/1.1 header and is completely transparent to the web page loading an object (resource).